# How would you go about allowing a program to install on a specific computer only

Tags: c#, locking

An example would be where you can lock your steam account to a particular computer.

My preferred language to achieve this would be C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `ManagementObjectSearcher` to get a unique info (like harddisk serial number) about that computer and put that security in my program so that it only works on that machine.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to use a combination of Environment.GetMachineName and Environment.GetUserName. (For extra security use hashing algorithms and passwords, but that's just common sense).

Obviously there's the issue of the user changing their user name or something, but if you're implementing this as something full-time and not just a one-off program, you're going to be wanting a remote server to store the locking details anyway.

Comment: You can use the MAC address also.

Comment: All of those things can be trivially spoofed. So this isn't real security, just making things harder.

Comment: The OP does not talk about security. But yes, anything can be spoofed. Even keys.

Comment: To be fair the asker doesn't give much detail at all, nor do they use the word 'security'. My solution is perfectly viable for one off programs, but as I mentioned if it's something large scale, they'll need a proper server anyway.